# When Bochner and Pettis integrals coincide?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

A well-known fact is that if a space $X$ is reflexive, then Dunford and Pettis integrals coincide. But I'm inerested in the relation between Bochner and Pettis integral. It seems obvious that if a function is Bochner integrable, then it is Pettis integrable as well. What are the necessary conditions so that they coincide?

I thought that $X$ being separable is enough. Then the function we integrate becomes strongly measurable. Is it enough, or maybe separability is too much?

Comment: If a function is Bochner integrable then its Bochner integral is equal to its Pettis integral. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, and also, a function is Pettis integrable plus propably something else  (what is that?) is Bochner integrable.

Comment: Bochner integrabilty is equivalent to strong measurability and finiteness of $\int \|f\|$. There is no other simpler condition under Pettis integrability.

Comment: So, if a function is Pettis integrable, then it is weakly measurable. And if a space is for instance  separable, then $f$ becomes strongly measurable. If in addition, $\int\|f\|<\infty$ then it becomes Bochner integrable.

Comment: Exactly. That is the best you can say.

Comment: Thank you so much!